# Why Nuxt3 shows "404 Page not found" error?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

I have Nuxt3 app, backend app and NGINX installed on my server. All requests that start with `/api` redirected to backend app, all requests that does not start with `/api` redirected to Nuxt3 app.

I have endpoint `localhost/api/data` which resolves to my backend app and returns some data:

`{firstkey: firstdata, secondkey: seconddata}`

I want to get this data in Nuxt3 app:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: "mycomponent",
  async setup() {
    console.log(await $fetch('http://localhost/api/data'));
  }
})
```

But when I'm running Nuxt3 app I get an error:

```
404
[GET] "http://localhost/api/data": 404 Page not found: /api/data
```

When i'm trying to acccess "http://localhost/api/data" with my browser I can see my data without any problems.

Why Nuxt can't load this page?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting the computer once it's installed? (for goofy as it sounds). I had this problem in general in databases with my system and my last resource always resulted to be a quick reboot.

Comment: I restarted docker containers and I still have this error.